# Square Waveform Generation

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I'm working on a stopwatch project in VHDL, but I don't know how to make the `CLK` square waveform of the counter?

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

 entity Circuit is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC := '0';
           CLR : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));
end Circuit;

architecture Behavioral of Circuit is

signal s: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR := "000000";

begin

process (CLK, CLR)
begin
if rising_edge(CLK) then
if CLR = '1' OR s = "111011" then
s <= "000000";
else
s <= s+1;
end if;
end if;
end process;
Q <= s;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: If you want to get meaningful answers, you need to provide some code to show what you've tried.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this code. Looks like it repeatedly counts from 0 to 59. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I need to make it count every second like a stopwatch.

Comment: Let me rephrase; what is the difference between what this code does, and what you want it to do?

Comment: If you want to increment counter every second, you just need to adjust clock frequency properly.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your clock is 1 MHz, but you want the seconds counter process to work at 1 Hz. You would need to divide the incoming clock by 1 million.

```
constant CLOCK_DIVIDER : integer := 1000000;
signal clock_divide_counter : integer range 0 to CLOCK_DIVIDER-1 := 0;
signal one_hz_pulse : std_logic := '0';
```

...

```
process (clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (clock_divide_counter = CLOCK_DIVIDER - 1) then
            clock_divide_counter <= 0;
            one_hz_pulse <= '1';
        else
            clock_divide_counter <= clock_divide_counter + 1;
            one_hz_pulse <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

then modify your existing process to only be enabled when the 1 Hz pulse is high:

```
process (CLK, CLR)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if (CLR = '1') then
            s <= "000000";
        elsif (one_hz_pulse = '1') then
            if s = "111011" then
                s <= "000000";
            else
                s <= s+1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I haven't run the code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: You should should swap the `one_hz_pulse` and the `CLR` condition, otherwise `CLR` is only recognized once in a second.

Comment: Thanks, change made. Couldn't swap them because then the count would only increment if CLR was asserted.