# Creating a real-time delay in Vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I want to write a design in which , a process gets activated exactly after 1 minute.

I have created one more process to create a delay using a counter incrementation, and toggling a signal , and giving that signal in the sensitivity list of the process that has to be delayed.

```
signal delay_over : std_logic;

process ( delay_over )
begin 
     if clk'event and clk '1' then
         --design
     end if;
end process;

delay:process ( clk )
variable counter : integer := 0;
begin 
--design to create delay
end process;
```

What is the value or and type of counter i should use to create a delay of exact 1 minute.

Answer (score 3):

Equating a **real time delay** in a synchronous design (any design with a clock) **is as simple as counting clocks**, or counting enables of a time base generated by counting clocks.

For example, say the smallest unit of real time you need to deal with is 1 second (that is, you will never need to deal with tenths, milliseconds, etc). Your timebase can then be seconds. **So you need to figure out how to convert from the period (duration) of a single clock to a second.**

Let's assume you have a 25MHz clock. That means there are 25e6 clocks in a second.  That means you need to count up to 25e6 (or (25e6)-1, depending how you set it up), reset the counter back to zero, and begin counting again.  Every time your counter reaches 0 (or 25e6, or any other single value in the count), you can pulse an enable for one clock cycle. **That enable is your "seconds" timebase.**

All your other logic can be referenced to the "seconds" timebase enable. To create a realtime delay of 10 seconds, you simply need to count 10 pulses of the seconds timebase enable.

Here is a snippet of an example, to give you the idea:

```
   timebase : process (I_CLK) is
   begin
      if (rising_edge(I_CLK)) then
         counter_1sec_en <= '0';
         if (counter < COUNTS_IN_1_SEC-1) then
            counter <= counter + 1;
         else
            counter_1sec_en <= '1';
            counter         <= (others => '0');
         end if;
      end if;
   end process timebase;

   delay : process (I_CLK) is
   begin
      if (rising_edge(I_CLK)) then
         seconds_delay_done <= '0';
         if (counter_1sec_en = '1') then
            if (seconds_delay < NUM_SECONDS_TO_DELAY-1) then
               seconds_delay <= seconds_delay + 1;
            else
               seconds_delay_done <= '1';
               seconds_delay <= (others => '0');
            end if;
         end if;
      end if;
   end process delay;
```

Some notes to go with this snippet:

- Everything is synchronous to your clock, `I_CLK`
- `COUNTS_IN_1_SEC` is a constant that is your clock frequency in Hz
- `counter_1sec_en` pulses once every second, for a single `I_CLK` cycle
- `NUM_SECONDS_TO_DELAY` is some number of seconds you want to delay. For example, 60 seconds.
- `seconds_delay_done` pulses for one `I_CLK` cycle when the delay has completed.
- You will likely need more control over when to arm/enable the delay, and possibly control over how many seconds to delay (i.e. `NUM_SECONDS_TO_DELAY` may not be a constant).

In your case, if you want something to be "activated" after 1 minute, you can use the `seconds_delay_done` enable to "kick off" whatever it is you want to start.

Also, see this nearly identical answer for a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948250/561560